# Update a dataframe with values from a second dataframe based on a filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
print df1
        name value a value b recommendation
a       Arn  1       30      Up
b       Bob  1       50      Wait
c       Cain 2       70      Up
d       Dain 3       80      Wait

print df2
        name value a value b recommendation
a       Arn  3       50      Up
b       Bob  2       90      Up
c       Cain 4       170     Up
d       Dain 9       280     Up
```

I'm trying to update df1 with df2 values where the recommendation is "Wait" on df1 using the update method:

```
df1.update(df2, filter_func = df1.loc[df1['recommendation'] == 'Wait'])
```

This isn't working. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT

Expected output would be:

```
print df1
        name value a value b recommendation
a       Arn  1       30      Up
b       Bob  2       90      Up
c       Cain 2       70      Up
d       Dain 9       280     Up
```

Comment: so Bob and Dain go from Wait to up?

Comment: provide the expected output df

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mask` , turn all to `np.nan` , then we using `combine_first`

```
df1=df1.mask(df1=='Wait').combine_first(df2)
df1
Out[621]: 
   name  valuea  valueb recommendation
a   Arn       1      30             Up
b   Bob       1      50             Up
c  Cain       2      70             Up
d  Dain       3      80             Up
```

If you need update whole row

```
df1.loc[(df1.recommendation!='Wait')].combine_first(df2)
Out[623]: 
   name  valuea  valueb recommendation
a   Arn     1.0    30.0             Up
b   Bob     2.0    90.0             Up
c  Cain     2.0    70.0             Up
d  Dain     9.0   280.0             Up
```